# prisma ORM error: Unique constraint failed on the constraint: `Comment_postId_key`

Tags: mysql, orm, prisma

I am using Prisma ORM with Mysql, I created three models: User, Post and Comment:

```
 model User {
      id          Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
      name        String      @db.VarChar(255)
      email       String      
      posts       Post[]
      profile     Profile?
      comments    Comment[]
    }

model Post {
  id          Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
  title       String      @db.VarChar(255)
  content     String?
  createdAt   DateTime    @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime    @updatedAt     
  author      User        @relation(fields: [authorId], references:[id])
  authorId    Int
  comments    Comment[]
}
model Comment {
  id          Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
  content     String
  post        Post        @relation(fields: [postId], references:[id])
  postId      Int         
  author      User        @relation(fields: [authorId], references:[id])
  authorId    Int                
}
```

I want to add an other comment for the the post with PostId=3 using the code :

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
    const prisma = new PrismaClient();
    async function main() {
        await prisma.comment.create({
            data:{
                content: 'an other comment on post 3',
                postId: 3,
                authorId: 2,
            }
        })
    };
    main().catch(e=>console.log(e))
```

I get an error:

PrismaClientKnownRequestError:
Invalid `prisma.comment.create()` invocation in
/home/houcem/Desktop/projects/Blog/test.ts:6:26

```
  3 const prisma = new PrismaClient();
  4 
  5 async function main() {
→ 6     await prisma.comment.create(
  Unique constraint failed on the constraint: `Comment_postId_key`
```

Comment: Would you please share the code for the prisma query (where the issue is occurring)?  An idea about what data exists in the `user` and `post` tables might also help.

Comment: I posted the details in the comment bellow

Comment: Hi, I'll have a look, but you should edit your question with the details you just provided. "Answers" are for answers to the question, not for adding details (which should go directly  in the question).

Comment: I'll do that, thank you

Comment: I tried replicating your exact setup (including the data) and the query you provided a while ago (you accidentally posted it as an answer). I seem to have no issue creating multiple comments. Are you sure you're using valid `postId` and `authorId` fields? I would also recommend using the [`connect` operator](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#connect-an-existing-record) instead of directly passing `postId` and `authorId`.

Comment: I used the connect operator and I get the same error, could you please show me the content of the Comment table you created

Comment: I found the solution, can I post it as an answer ?

Comment: Sure, that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

if you created a comment entity brefore with a manually set id, then the automatic id generation is broken, verify that you never set id manually when letting prisma generate automatic ids

Comment: I added a record to a table which has just two fields (first and last names) and uses a composite primary key (i.e. combines the two fields and doesn't have a separate 'id' column). I never thought that adding a record manually would cause any problems but it turned out that was the cause of this same error in my case. The lesson I learned is to do everything on the database through Prisma.